# Probability of head given that heads already appeared in the first N+M tosses

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-variables, conditional-probability

I have the following problem

An honest coin is tossed. What is the conditional probability that it appears head for the first time on the $N$ th toss, knowing that it has come up at least one head appears on the first $N+M$ tosses.

I think it can be solved in the following way
\begin{align*}
A & = \text{appears heads for the first time on the $N$ th toss} \\
B & = \text{at least one head appears on the first $N+M$ tosses}
\end{align*}
then
\begin{align*}
P(A|B) &  = \frac{P(B|A) P(A)}{P(B)} \\
& = \frac{P(B|A) \frac{1}{2} (1-1/2)^{N-1}  }{\sum_{i = 1}^{N+M} \binom{N+M}{i} \frac{1}{2} (1-\frac{1}{2 })^{N+M-i}}
\end{align*}

how can it be calculated $P(B|A)$? could be $\frac{1}{2} (1-1/2)^{N-1} + \frac{1}{2} (1-1/2)^{N-1}  \cdot \sum_{i = 1}^{M} \binom{M}{i} \frac{1}{2^i} (1-1/2)^{M-i} $? because we want at least one head to appear, but the first coin appears in the $N$th position, so the others can only come out in $M$ positions

Greetings

Comment: P(B|A)=1 because given that there is a heads on Nth toss, one head has indeed appeared in the first N+M tosses.

Comment: $P(B)=1-\frac{1}{2^{N+M}}$ as the complement of $N+M$ tails